# What values do Kafka offsets have and what do they mean?

Tags: apache-kafka

I understand that the offset is used to determine which messages a consumer wants. But is the offset a hash? Is it a timestamp? Is it simply an integer, where `3` could mean the last 3 messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An offset is "a sequential id number [..] that uniquely identifies each record within the partition" ([source: Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_topics)).

It starts at 0, which is the first record ever published in a given partition. It increases monotonically with each record added to the partition.

Comment: Who keeps track of the current offset? Is it the consumer?

Comment: @MartinThoma offset is kept in special topic, that is called __consumer_offsets